# React npm start is not working and no error is displaying

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-scripts, npm-start

When I try to execute scripts with npm start, it doesn't work and just displays the script value without throwing any errors and nothing happens. However, if I try to run next start, it works.

My Package.json

```
 "name": "cms-app",
  "version": "0.3.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "eslint './src/**/*' --ext .tsx,.ts",
    "prettier": "prettier --write src/",
    "test": "is-ci-cli \"test:coverage\" \"test:watch\"",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:coverage": "jest --watch=false --coverage",
    "build": "next build",
    "export": "next export"
  }
```

Bash Terminal

```
test1@PC-0000 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/RWA (Releasev1.5)
$ npm run start

> cms-app@0.3.0 dev C:\Users\test1\Desktop\RWA
> next start


test1@PC-0000 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/RWA (Releasev1.5)
$ npm run dev

> cms-app@0.3.0 dev C:\Users\test1\Desktop\RWA
> next dev
```

Already set the ignore-scripts to false

Comment: you should try this command : `npm start`

Comment: Already did npm start, npm run-script start and npm start same result